# Error when start spring Could not find class [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport]

Tags: java, spring

I use IntelliJ to develop my project. The project starts off without any framework, later on I was trying to add spring boot by adding dependencies in Maven. Then I got this error when I trying to start the server.

```
ERROR : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport]
```

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/88I7J.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't have **org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport** packages
in your project

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

so you'd better write this sentence in pom.xml